# jqgrid resizing(landscape to portrait) very slow when it is put inside an iframe and viewed on an ipad

Tags: ipad, iframe, jqgrid, resize

jqgrid is inside an iframe. It is resizing very slow when changed from landscape to portrait view in an ipad. Right now I am using resize javascript function to resize the grid on window resize. I know it is the cause, Is there a better solution to avoid this problem?

```
$("#Mygrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        url: '#',
        colNames: [...],
        colModel: [...],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        gridview: true,
        altRows: true,
        altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
        autowidth: true,
        footerrow: true,
        loadonce: true,
        rowNum:10000
        });
```

is jqgrid code

```
 $(window).bind('resize', function () {
    var statusGridWidth = $('#wrapper').width();
        $("#Mygrid").setGridWidth(statusGridWidth);
}).trigger('resize');
```

is the code to resize.

Comment: Can you add jqgrid code....

Comment: Hi Krishna, I added the code in my question above. Little more info, it resizes quick when i simulate in chrome dev tools in device mode (iPad mode), but fails when I actually see in the iPad.